# AD FS Setting up - what user rights required?

Tags: active-directory, adfs

I am reading [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731443(v=ws.10).aspx). Is this the latest?

May I know what rights is required to set up and configure the Federation Server?

Is the Federation Server usually the responsibility of the domain owner?  If I am a third-party (web) application supplier, should I expect that the Federation Server be provided by the customer and I should just focus on the FS Web Agent?

Comment: Web agent? That's ADFS 1.1. Do Not Use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current list of requirements for setup of ADFS is here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dn554247.aspx

The section you're looking for:

> Permissions requirements
>
> The administrator that performs the installation and the initial
>   configuration of AD FS must have **domain administrator** permissions in
>   the local domain (in other words, the domain to which the federation
>   server is joined to.)

As an application developer - and a third party one at that - the expectation should definitely be that the customer sets up, manages and maintains their own ADFS infrastructure.